# How to replace the data validation input message with a textbox

Tags: excel, validation, textbox, vba

Input message data validation is limited to 255 characters and 9 lines. How would like to replace it with a textbox. Would it be possible? 
Here you go my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim arr, cellVal As Variant
    Set rng = Range("A1:A10")
    arr = rng.Value
    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then

    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            cellVal = arr(i, j)
            Select Case cellVal
              Case Is = "A"
                  rng(i, j).Validation.InputMessage = "Presentation and history:" & vbTab & vbCrLf & _
                "One eye or both eyes" & vbTab & vbCrLf & _
                "Gritty sensation/itch versus pain" & vbTab & vbCrLf & _
                "Photophobia" & vbTab & vbCrLf & _
                "Visual change" & vbTab & vbCrLf & _
                "Discharge present" & vbTab & vbCrLf & _
                "Injury" & vbTab & vbCrLf & _
                "Foreign body" & vbTab & vbCrLf & _
                "History of allergy or hay fever" & vbTab
              Case Is = "B"
                  rng(i, j).Validation.InputMessage = TextBox1.Text
              Case Is = "C"
                  rng(i, j).Validation.InputMessage = "Carrot"
              Case Else
                  rng(i, j).Validation.InputMessage = "Something   else"
            End Select
        Next j
    Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Case "A" shows the limit of the data validation message. I would like to replace it with TextBox1 as shown in case "B". Please let me know if it is possible. 
Regards 
Tommaso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mimic the behaviour by making various text boxes visible like so:

first create a number or ordinary text boxes - using multiple fonts, font sizes, colors, bells & whistles

[image: create textboxes]

then write a `Selection_Change` trigger ... very similar to what you did (noting that text boxes from the Insert menu are `Shapes()` )

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim MyTB As Shape
    ' hide all boxes
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox 1").Visible = msoFalse
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox 2").Visible = msoFalse
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox 3").Visible = msoFalse

    ' working on B1:B10 in order not to disturb data validation in A1:A10
    If Not Intersect(Target, [B1:B10]) Is Nothing Then

        ' assign correct TextBox to MyTB
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case "A", "a"
                Set MyTB = ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox 1")
            Case "B", "b"
                Set MyTB = ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox 2")
            Case Else
                Set MyTB = ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox 3")
        End Select

        ' position MyTB one cell right/down from Cursor (Target) and make visible
        MyTB.Left = Target(1, 2).Left
        MyTB.Top = Target(2, 2).Top
        MyTB.Visible = msoTrue

    End If
End Sub
```

and you should be done ?!?

[image]

(TextBox content thankfully stolen from https://www.lipsum.com/)

Comment: Hi Mike still on the same code. I have tried to introduce it in a worksheet with another macros and I don't know why it doesn't make the magic there. Do you know what can be the cause. Your help is really appreciated. Thanks again for the genius code you provide me

Comment: That was a problem with my laptop. Now it works fine. Thanks again Mike